# Excessive DNS Update requests

Tags: windows, dhcp

I have a curious situation and I can't find any good reason why its happening.  Its not causing any noticeable problems, just something I'd like to resolve.  From my Server12 dhcp logs, these entries repeat ad nauseam.  I've logged in to the client, no reports of IP conflicts from any users, confirmed dhcp settings on client, and confirmed switch port settings.  This is the only client which appears to be having this issue to this degree.  There is another one but the requests are much less frequent.

```
30,01/22/15,01:51:46,DNS Update Request,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,
11,01/22/15,01:51:46,Renew,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,0023AE81D7A9,,1501549107,0,,,,0x4D534654    20352E30,MSFT 5.0,,,
32,01/22/15,01:51:46,DNS Update Successful,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,

30,01/22/15,02:08:42,DNS Update Request,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,
11,01/22/15,02:08:42,Renew,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,0023AE81D7A9,,261419984,0,,,,0x4D5346542   0352E30,MSFT 5.0,,,
32,01/22/15,02:08:42,DNS Update Successful,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,


30,01/22/15,02:08:45,DNS Update Request,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,
11,01/22/15,02:08:45,Renew,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,0023AE81D7A9,,261419984,0,,,,0x4D53465420352E30,MSFT 5.0,,,
32,01/22/15,02:08:45,DNS Update Successful,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,


30,01/22/15,02:17:19,DNS Update Request,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,
11,01/22/15,02:17:19,Renew,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,0023AE81D7A9,,1971122446,0,,,,0x4D534654   20352E30,MSFT 5.0,,,
32,01/22/15,02:17:19,DNS Update Successful,10.0.2.154,RTWoodshop109.snow.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like its your client who is trying to update a record .

Do you have a reverse record zone ? It could be a problem on dhcp with right to update the zone .

Its new or a old problem ?